# Border keeps being under first line

Tags: css

I am trying to add border to a bottom of the text, however whenever the text has two lines, the border keeps under the first sentence. It should take the second sentence and move 15 px from it. How can I fix this?
The second red line should be under word `dawdwada`

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}

.link {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.link a::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="title">
  <div class="link">
  <a>waddwaudwahidauidwa</a>
  </div>
    <div class="link">
  <a>waddwaudwahidauidwa dawdwada </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: bottom:0 instead of top:15px

Answer (score 1):

instead of using ::after, you can just use border-bottom on link

Answer (score 0):

Use text-decorations instead of borders

```html
  <a style="text-decoration: underline;">waddwaudwahidauidwa dawdwada </a>
```

go to :[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text_decoration.asp)